# Visualising trigonometry Identity

Tags: trigonometry, intuition, visualization

Can someone help me visualize this trigonometry Identity

Prove that :

$$1+\tan A\times\tan \frac{A}{2} = \sec A$$

I got the answer by manipulating the lhs substitution lots of mundane stuff but without a pen and paper and say a magical ability to never be able to visualize text in my mind, I wouldn't have been able to visualize this geometrically and understand how $\sec A$ is achieved. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Consider a right triangle with one size equal to 1. AD is the is angle A bisector and DE is perpendicular to hypotenuse. Since ABD and AED are congruent, $AE =1$ and $DE = \tan {\frac{A}{2}}$. You just need to write tangent of angle C in DEC and ABC.

$\tan{C} = \frac{1}{\tan{A}} = \frac{\tan{\frac{A}{2}}}{\sec{A}-1} \Rightarrow \tan{A}\tan{\frac{A}{2}}=\sec{A}-1$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Such a neat proof, amazing. Thankyou